# Parse Minecraft's raw JSON text format into HTML using PHP

Tags: php, json, minecraft

I want to parse the raw JSON text format (which is a rich text format used by Minecraft) into HTML, so I can fetch the data from a Minecraft server then put it on a website. But, searches return no relevant information (aside from the legacy color codes, which are way simpler). I have no idea how to do it. Is there any library that might make it simpler or any hints on this? Here's an example:

```json
{"extra":[{"color":"light_purple","text":"... "},{"color":"green","text":"hello world"}],"text":""}
```

Comment: What does the actual data look like? Could you edit your question and add that?

Comment: Yeah, sure, but it probably won't contain everything since then it will get massive.

Comment: I just need a snippet so I have something to work with.

Comment: I have added one, hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for the instance that you have given, this code will probably work:

```php
<?php 
        $jsonString = '{"extra":[{"color":"light_purple","text":"... "},{"color":"green","text":"hello world"}],"text":""}';
        $obj = json_decode($jsonString);

        foreach($obj->extra as $item){
                echo "<span class='".$item->color."'>".$item->text."</span>";           
        }       
?>
```

What I would recommend is including a .css file as well containing the colors inside of classes like so:

```css
.light_purple {
    color:#FF55FF;
}

.green {
    color:#55FF55;
}
```

I actually found a good resource containing the actual hex codes for those minecraft colors [here.](https://www.digminecraft.com/lists/color_list_pc.php). There really aren't that many colors so it shouldn't be too bad to add onto your project!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but there's "shorthands," like ["a", "b", "c"] is equivalent to {"text":"a",extra:["b", "c"]}

Comment: @soshimee_ you should be able to go a step deeper by just adding another arrow or loop if it's an array using the -> thing in PHP.

Comment: Yep, I did it with recursion.